# MusixTeX Cajon drum for 16th doesn't show upper beam

Tags: musixtex, musixper

I want to make simple rhythm notes of Cajon, this is what I want

[image: I want to get such 16th notes]

I wrote the same thing in below bar 3, but missed something.

[image: But my bar 3 looks different]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{musixtex}
\input{musixper} % percussion additions (percussion note heads, etc.)

\begin{document}

\begin{music}
\instrumentnumber{1}
\generalmeter{\meterfrac44}
\setclefsymbol1\drumclef
\parindent0pt\startpiece
\leftrepeat
\notes \ibu1m0\qb1f\doqb1n\qb1j\tbu1\doqb1n \en
\notes \ibu1m0\qb1f\doqb1n\qb1j\tbu1\doqb1n \en
\bar
\notes \ibbu1m0\qb1f\doqb1n\doqb1n\tbbu1\doqb1n \en
\notes \ibbu1m0\qb1j\doqb1n\doqb1n\tbbu1\doqb1n \en
\notes \ibbu1m0\qb1f\doqb1n\doqb1n\tbbu1\doqb1n \en
\notes \ibbu1m0\qb1j\doqb1n\doqb1n\tbbu1\doqb1n \en
\bar
\notes\Qqbbu fhge\Qqbbl jhgi\en
\notes\Qqbbu fhge\Qqbbl jhgi\en
\setrightrepeat\endpiece
\end{music}

\end{document}
```

Compiled with 3-passing

```
pdflatex example.tex
musixflx example
pdflatex example.tex
pdflatex example.tex
```

**UPDATE with solution**

According to the answer together with comments, the problem is about ending a beam, the [doc](https://ctan.gust.org.pl/tex-archive/macros/musixtex/doc/musixdoc.pdf) says:

> The termination of a given beam must be declared before coding the last spacing note connected to that beam.

So 16th notes is initialed by `\ibbu{n}{p}{s}` should be terminated by `\tbu{n}`

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{musixtex}
\input{musixper} % percussion additions (percussion note heads, etc.)

\begin{document}

\begin{music}
\instrumentnumber{1}
\generalmeter{\meterfrac44}
\setclefsymbol1\drumclef
\parindent0pt\startpiece
\leftrepeat
\notes \ibu1m0\qb1f\doqb1n\qb1j\tbu1\doqb1n \en
\notes \ibu1m0\qb1f\doqb1n\qb1j\tbu1\doqb1n \en
\bar
\notes \ibbu1m0\qb1f\doqb1n\doqb1n\tbu1\doqb1n \en
\notes \ibbu1m0\qb1j\doqb1n\doqb1n\tbu1\doqb1n \en
\notes \ibbu1m0\qb1f\doqb1n\doqb1n\tbu1\doqb1n \en
\notes \ibbu1m0\qb1j\doqb1n\doqb1n\tbu1\doqb1n \en
\bar
\notes\Qqbbu fhge\Qqbbl jhgi\en
\notes\Qqbbu fhge\Qqbbl jhgi\en
\setrightrepeat\endpiece
\end{music}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: I like the music :-) +1.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

musixtex requires three passes to properly space music.  Change the file name to something.ltx and execute

musixtex something.ltx

and everything will work.  Please read musixdoc.pdf for documentation.

Comment: thank you, but it doesn't solve the problem, the upper line is still missing

Comment: Are you using the musixtex script to compile your example?  I don't know what you mean by "the upper line is still missing".

Comment: Replace \tbbu1 by \tbu1.